# Add comma between foreach looped items but not at end

Tags: php

I'd like to achieve on adding a comma between my authors in my foreach but each time I make any references, it adds a comma at the end also.

Here is what I have below:

```
<div class="four-sixths first">
    <a href="<?php echo 'URL' ?>"><img class="mb-20" src="<?= $recipe->get_thumbnail() ?>" alt=""/></a>
    <h2 class="mb-5"><?= $recipe->get_title() ?></h2>
    <span><?= $recipe->get_date() ?></span> -
        <?php foreach ($recipe->get_authors() as $profile): ?>
            <a href="<?= $profile->get_url() ?>"><?= $profile->get_name() ?></a>,
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <p><?= $recipe->get_content() ?></p>
</div>
```

Which gives me the following results:
[image]

How can I prevent a comma at the end?

Comment: Add to an array and `implode` or use `trim`

Comment: Is this pure PHP?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, since I'm using `->{{method_name}}` - It's a lot harder than it looks.

Comment: @GetSet, PHP and HTML.

Comment: I meant the PHP parts. Are you using a framework?

Comment: @AbraCadaver, how can you add to an array when the object is calling in methods?

Comment: @GetSet, no it's pure OOP PHP - I just have a class that has all the methods that are being pulled in.

Comment: Ok just checking. See my answer.

Comment: `join(",", array_map(function ($profile) { return $profile->get_name(); }, $recipe->get_authors()))` should give you a comma-separated list of the names. You could ofcourse return the whole  `<a href="...">...</a>` tag aswell

Comment: I didn't see any `->{{method_name}}` in your code but I added a simple example with `implode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were skeptical about `implode`, here's a simple example (just showing the loop):

```
    <?php foreach ($recipe->get_authors() as $profile):
        $links[] = '<a href="' . $profile->get_url() . '">' . $profile->get_name() . '</a>';
    endforeach; ?>
    <?= implode(', ', $links); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to test it but basically store results to `$authors` first, and in this way you can `count` it without recalling the method `get_authors`. While `$cnt` keeps track *base 1* and can be compared directly on the length.

```
<?php

$authors = $recipe->get_authors();
$cnt = 0;
?>
<div class="four-sixths first">
    <a href="<?php echo 'URL' ?>"><img class="mb-20" src="<?= $recipe->get_thumbnail() ?>" alt=""/></a>
    <h2 class="mb-5"><?= $recipe->get_title() ?></h2>
    <span><?= $recipe->get_date() ?></span> -
        <?php foreach ($authors as $profile) { $cnt++; ?>
            <a href="<?= $profile->get_url() ?>"><?= $profile->get_name() ?></a><?php
                if ($cnt < count($authors)) echo ",";
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <p><?= $recipe->get_content() ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually worked great! I just have one small question, after the first name, it adds a space between both names as such "Test" , "Hello" .. How can I adjust it so it doesn't add a space after the first name as such "Test", "Hello".

Comment: I would appreciate the upvote @SLE. I'll have a look at your code again for this other problem.

Comment: Definitely deserved @GetSet - It's just something that I wanted to see what might be causing it.

Comment: Possibly you could manipulate the result of `$profile->get_name()` *before* echoing it out?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `join`:

```
<div class="four-sixths first">
    <a href="<?php echo 'URL' ?>"><img class="mb-20" src="<?= $recipe->get_thumbnail() ?>" alt=""/></a>
    <h2 class="mb-5"><?= $recipe->get_title() ?></h2>
    <span><?= $recipe->get_date() ?></span> - <?= join(", ", array_map(function ($profile) { return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $profile->get_url(), $profile->get_name()); }, $recipe->get_authors())) ?>
    <p><?= $recipe->get_content() ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: when I attempt this - It gives me an undefined `->get_name() and get_url(), so I'm guessing at some point $profile isn't reachable.

Comment: I assumed your `$recipe->get_authors()` method always returns an array of `Profile` instances (or an empty array for recipes without authors, if that's possible in your design).

Comment: that is true, it was giving the error inside the getter and setter.